# Unable to remove Null Values and receive output

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am working in Hive and trying to query a table that would be extracted from another table that has NULL values. The query runs fine but eventually, the new table comes out to be completely blank.

hive> select * from makemodelpricenn limit 10;

Gives output that looks like:

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, querying with NULLs removed gives out nothing:

```
select * from makemodelpricenn where fuel_type != "NULL";
```

Output:

[image]

How can I query a table that contains no NULL values and has clean data?

Comment: have you tried `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`?

Comment: Yes. In fact I tried != NULL only after trying IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try

```
select * from makemodelpricenn where fuel_type != 'NULL';
```

If it doesn't work then try the below DDL

```
ALTER TABLE makemodelpricenn SET TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = 'NULL');
```

and then use

```
select * from makemodelpricenn where fuel_type is not  NULL;
```

Comment: Hi I used the following code:

hive> kaustubhmulay2907@hadoopcluster-1-m:~$  create table makemodelpricenn select * from makemodelprice where maker is not NULL and model is not NULL and fuel_type is not NULL;

However, when I query the first 20 rows, there is no result. Any ideas?